# How Can i use Assisted Service Module (ASM) functionality from Back Office Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to SAP Hybris.
I has implemented ASM addon and it is working fine on storefront.
***I want to use ASM functionality in Back Office.***
Is there any way through which we can enable ASM in Back Office or we can not do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB Assisted Service Module (ASM) is functionality, where backend agent can assist end customers, so it's only for the user storefront not for the backend tools(backoffice, HAC etc.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can i find Launch ASM link anywhere in back office?

Comment: Yes you can launch ASM link from smartedit backoffice